# Azure Data Storage pipeline to purge SQL table

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, pipeline, azure-data-factory, purge

I am wondering if I can create an Azure pipeline and have it run a proc that purges my Azure SQL table.

I am still new to the concept of data factories and I see that most often than not, the data factories have pipelines to copy over data from either a blob to azure SQL/on premise SQL or the other way around.

I am trying to write a data factory pipeline that will purge old records in my Azure SQL DB and was hoping if anyone can point me in the right direction. Can I still use the Azure data factory for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to use Azure Automation instead of ADF to schedule stored procedure execution. You will find examples [here](http://blog.exsilio.com/all/sql-azure-job-agent-using-azure-automation-2/) and [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/). Below is the code you need to implement on Azure Automation:

```
workflow NAME-OF-YOUR-WORKFLOW
{
    Write-Output "JOB START BEFORE INLINESCRIPT"

    inlinescript
    {
        Write-Output "JOB START"
        # Create connection to Master DB
        $MasterDatabaseConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $MasterDatabaseConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=YOUR-DATABASE-SERVER-NAME.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=YOUR-DATABASE-NAME;Integrated Security=False;User ID=YOUR-DATABASE-USERNAME;Password=YOUR-DATABASE-PASSWORD;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
        $MasterDatabaseConnection.Open()

        Write-Output "CONNECTION OPEN"

        # Create command
        $MasterDatabaseCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $MasterDatabaseCommand.Connection = $MasterDatabaseConnection
        $MasterDatabaseCommand.CommandText = "YOUR-PROCEDURE-NAME"

        Write-Output "DATABASE COMMAND TEXT ASSIGNED"

        # Execute the query
        $MasterDatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Write-Output "EXECUTING QUERY"

        # Close connection to Master DB
        $MasterDatabaseConnection.Close() 

        Write-Output "CONNECTION CLOSED"
    }    
    Write-Output "WORK END - AFTER INLINESCRIPT"
}
```

To learn more about Azure automation, please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-intro).

Hope this helps.